# Installation of reCAPTCHA plugin in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm trying to install reCAPTCHA for a website I'm doing on Grails and I'm following the instructions provided by Grails in their [website](http://grails.org/plugin/recaptcha). I've successfully added

```
compile ':recaptcha:0.6.7'
```

in the plugins of in BuildConfig.groovy, and the next step was to run the command

```
grails recaptcha-quickstart
```

but for some reason, the command isn't found and gave me suggestions instead. Now, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Run `grails compile` first. This will trigger dependency resolution and "install" the plugin, and then its scripts will be available and you can run `grails recaptcha-quickstart`

Comment: Would it be fair to characterize the need to do this as a bug in Grails? It seems to me that dependency resolution should be triggered when any `grails` command is run.

Comment: It would be nice to have a "lite" dependency check, e.g. one that just caches previously declared and resolved plugins and libs, diffs that against the current, and runs the full resolve if there's a change. As it is now the dependency check can take a while, so it shouldn't be enabled for every command. But it's pretty simple to just always run compile after changing BuildConfig.groovy. Another option might be a plugin that hooks into the script running and detects that a script isn't found, and runs dependency resolution, and retries the script afterwards. Probably more work than it's worth.

Comment: Even something as simple as appending "please run 'grails compile' then try again" to the error message that is displayed when executing a script fails would go a long way. If you don't know about this issue then you can really spend a lot of time trying to figure out why the script isn't working.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do that if the script really doesn't exist. There is support already for a "did you mean?" prompt if you type something close to an existing script. But really people just get into the habit of always running compile after changing BuildConfig.groovy.